# PHP Script for Counter

Tags: php, counter

I am currently working on a project on the USHAHIDI platform. It is a website that will be fighting against corruption in the Republic of Guinea. Users can report incidences of corruption via the website, thus creating a data map for the Country.

I want to add a functionality where as users have the option to add the amount involved (in terms of currency) and the website can execute that entry and display it somewhere on the reports page and that amount will increment every time there is a new entry. What i am trying to achieve is to show the cost of corruption in terms of its economics.

I will give you two example:

1. Mr X was forced to pay a bribe of $100 to get a license. He goes on our website and fill in the report form. He enters the amount and submit the report.
   Now when the report is showing on the site, Under the heading COST OF CORRUPTION, it will show $100.
2. Mr Y was victim of the same type of corruption but he paid $200. He goes and report on our site with his amount. 
   Now on the sites we have 2 reports and Under the heading COST OF CORRUPTION: the amount is $300.

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when you post questions. It's unnecessary - we'll see your question without it - and won't get you answers faster. It's also very annoying and makes text harder to read; that's why they invented the Shift key in the first place. You obviously know how to use it properly from your question body; please use it in the subject line as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's two basic ways to do this either hold the value in a database or in a flat file. When someone posts a new bride add that to the current value and rewrite it out. Every time the site comes up read the value from the file or database. This is really basic stuff here.